# Double Render Error on Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I can't understand this Double Render Error on Create Method.

The problem is that Create Method has to redirect to an object that is not specific, due the fact that the object of Create Method has a polymorphic class (Commentary - Commentable).

I wish to create a commentary, link it to a object (Appointment, Person, ...), and redirect to the object (redirect_to @objeto), not to the commentary index. What should I do?

The code (comentarios_controller.rb) basically is:

```
def create

    #Verifica o objeto
    @objeto = nil
    tipo = params[:comentable_type]
    case tipo
        when "Comercial::Oportunidade"
            @objeto = Comercial::Oportunidade.find_by_id(params[:comentable_id])
        when "Comercial::Compromisso"
            @objeto = Comercial::Compromisso.find_by_id(params[:comentable_id])
    end

    @comentario=Comercial::Comentario.new(params[:comercial_comentario])
    @comentario.organizacoes<<current_empresa
    @comentario.usuario = current_usuario

    create! do |success, failure|
  if success
    @objeto.comentarios << @comentario
    flash[:success] = I18n.t 'activerecord.successful.messages.created.m', :model => @comentario.class.model_name.human
    redirect_to @objeto
  else
    flash.discard
  end
end
end
```

Using Rails 3.2.2

Comment: Where is the code for create! ?

Comment: It comes from InheritedResources (https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with Inherited Resources (and I see that the author no longer recommends its use), but it does seem that you're not using it correctly here. The example given that is most similar to your usage looks like this:

```
class ProjectsController < InheritedResources::Base
  def update
    update! do |success, failure|
      failure.html { redirect_to project_url(@project) }
    end
  end
end
```

Note the way that it uses the `failure` parameter -- it's not a boolean, and presumably it expects to take a block like the one shown here: `{ redirect_to ... }`. So I think you should try rewriting this part to look more like:

```
create! do |success, failure|
  success.html {
    @objeto.comentarios << @comentario
    flash[:success] = I18n.t 'activerecord.successful.messages.created.m', :model => @comentario.class.model_name.human
    redirect_to @objeto
  }
  failure.html { flash.discard }
end
```